# Gameboy emulator testing strategies?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, emulation

I'm writing a gameboy emulator, and am struggling with making sure opcodes are emulated correctly. Certain operations set flag registers, and it can be hard to track whether the flag is set correctly, and where.

I want to write some sort of testing framework, but thought it'd be worth asking here for some help. Currently I see a few options:

Unit test each and every opcode with several test cases. Issues are there are 256 8 bit opcodes and 50+ (can't remember exact number) 16 bit opcodes. This would take a long time to do properly.

Write some sort of logging framework that logs a stacktrace at each operation and compares it to other established emulators. This would be pretty quick to do, and allows a fairly rapid overview of what exactly went wrong. The log file would look a bit like this:

```
...
PC = 212 Just executed opcode 7c - Register: AF: 5 30 BC: 0 13 HL: 5 ce DE: 1 cd SP: ffad
PC = 213 Just executed opcode 12 - Register: AF: 5 30 BC: 0 13 HL: 5 ce DE: 1 cd SP: ffad
...
```

Cons are I need to modify the source of another emulator to output the same form. And there's no guarantee the opcode is correct as it assumes the other emulator is.

What else should I consider?

Here is my code if it helps: https://github.com/dbousamra/scalagb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the best idea is the one you already mentioned:

- take an existing emulator that is well known and you have the source code. let's call it *master emulator*
- take some ROM that you can use to test
- test these ROMs in the emulator that is known to work well.
- modify the *master emulator* so it produces log while it is running for each opcode that it executes.
- do the same in your own emulator
- compare the output

I think this one has more advantage:

- you will have the log file from a good emulator
- the outcome of the test can be evaluated much faster
- you can use more than one emulator
- you can go deeper later like putting memory to the log and see the differences between the two implementations.

Comment: I like the idea of comparing memory maps at certain points in time.

Comment: Okay I've added some testing to compare against a stack trace from another emulator (JavaBoy). Works well.

Comment: A problem with comparing with other emulators is that many emulators are not very accurate. I suggest testing with dedicated test roms instead.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra I know it's a little late (uh... 5 years? :P) but could I have a compiled verison of the edited Javaboy? I've come across the same problem as you, except I can't find another working emulator that I can change and compile. :/ Thanks!

Comment: @TheAbelo2 Sorry mate I no longer have the code :( I would ask on http://reddit.com/r/emudev

Answer (score 7):

You could use already established test roms. I would recommend Blargg's test roms. You can get them from here: http://gbdev.gg8.se/files/roms/blargg-gb-tests/.

Comment: Yeah Test roms are great. But how do you test your CPU with them, without having a working PPU?

Comment: Blargg's test roms also write to the gameboy's link port, so you could make a function which just prints the characters being sent through the link port. The test roms are quite well documented if you checkout the readme:s.

Comment: The link you gave is dead. Here is another one http://gbdev.gg8.se/files/roms/blargg-gb-tests/

Comment: @BoredT: Thank you for pointing it out! I updated my answer with your updated link.